# How to get lineage for a Dataflow Job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How can we get lineage for a dataflow job

I am trying to fetch atleast the source and destination names from a job and if possible find out the transformation applied on the pcollection in the pipeline, something like a trace of the function calls. I have been analyzing the logs for different kind of jobs, but could not figure out a definite way to fetch any of the informations I am looking for.